# Gradle fails to find any remote libraries

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I'm using Android Studio 1.0.1 and Gradle 2.2.1, and Gradle can not download any libraries from jcenter or maven central. I specifically need joda time and expandable text view, but it seems that no matter what dependency I add, Gradle refuses to find it. Here's my build.gradle files:

## Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

## Module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.testOrg"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':appmsglibrary')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':authenticationActivity')
    compile project(':slidinguppanellibrary')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+'
    compile files('libs/HockeySDK-3.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
}
```

If I go into the project settings and add dependencies through the GUI, I can search for each one of these so I know that gradle knows they exist at that point. But no matter what I've tried, it always fails to sync when I have a remote library added as a dependency. Any thoughts on how to go about fixing this? I've tried uninstalling everything (Android Studio, Gradle, SDKs and tools, etc) but still have the same issue. My colleague is working on the same code base and gradle syncs just fine for him.

### Result of running gradle from the command line

I ran this command from the project root `./gradlew --stacktrace --debug`

```
18:00:47.862 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
18:00:47.865 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
18:00:47.867 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
18:00:47.868 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
18:00:47.869 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring root project 'App-Studio'.
18:00:47.870 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
18:00:47.871 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0.
18:00:47.872 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
18:00:47.872 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]          :App-Studio:unspecified
18:00:47.873 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       > org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
18:00:47.874 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
18:00:47.876 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
18:00:47.878 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'App-Studio'.
18:00:47.878 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
18:00:47.879 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
18:00:47.880 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
18:00:47.881 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
18:00:47.882 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
18:00:47.882 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
18:00:47.884 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
18:00:47.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
18:00:47.886 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
18:00:47.887 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
18:00:47.888 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
18:00:47.889 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
18:00:47.890 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
18:00:47.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
18:00:47.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
18:00:47.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
18:00:47.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
18:00:47.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
18:00:47.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
18:00:47.897 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
18:00:47.898 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
18:00:47.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
18:00:47.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
18:00:47.901 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
18:00:47.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
18:00:47.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
18:00:47.903 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
18:00:47.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
18:00:47.905 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
18:00:47.905 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
18:00:47.906 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
18:00:47.906 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
18:00:47.907 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
18:00:47.907 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:52)
18:00:47.908 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
18:00:47.909 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:110)
18:00:47.909 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:180)
18:00:47.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:444)
18:00:47.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:205)
18:00:47.911 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
18:00:47.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.defineScriptHandlerClassScope(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:142)
18:00:47.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:60)
18:00:47.913 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:131)
18:00:47.913 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
18:00:47.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
18:00:47.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
18:00:47.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
18:00:47.916 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 30 more
18:00:47.917 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0.
18:00:47.918 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Required by:
18:00:47.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     :App-Studio:unspecified
18:00:47.920 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:81)
18:00:47.921 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainAdapter.resolve(RepositoryChainAdapter.java:69)
18:00:47.921 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:44)
18:00:47.922 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:577)
18:00:47.922 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:587)
18:00:47.923 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:272)
18:00:47.923 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:246)
18:00:47.924 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:156)
18:00:47.925 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveDependencyGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:94)
18:00:47.925 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:84)
18:00:47.926 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:122)
18:00:47.926 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:88)
18:00:47.927 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:136)
18:00:47.928 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
18:00:47.928 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
18:00:47.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:88)
18:00:47.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:42)
18:00:47.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
18:00:47.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:187)
18:00:47.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
18:00:47.932 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
18:00:47.932 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
18:00:47.933 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
18:00:47.933 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:40)
18:00:47.934 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:45)
18:00:47.934 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.java:55)
18:00:47.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:47)
18:00:47.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:46)
18:00:47.936 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:250)
18:00:47.937 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
18:00:47.937 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
18:00:47.938 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:442)
18:00:47.938 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 39 more
18:00:47.939 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
18:00:47.939 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
18:00:47.940 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:186)
18:00:47.940 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
18:00:47.941 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
18:00:47.941 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
18:00:47.942 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:118)
18:00:47.942 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:111)
18:00:47.943 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:87)
18:00:47.944 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:78)
18:00:47.944 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:66)
18:00:47.945 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:70)
18:00:47.945 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:53)
18:00:47.946 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:36)
18:00:47.946 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:39)
18:00:47.947 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:72)
18:00:47.948 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:91)
18:00:47.948 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveMetaDataArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:57)
18:00:47.949 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:162)
18:00:47.949 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:141)
18:00:47.950 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:82)
18:00:47.950 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:391)
18:00:47.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess$2.run(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:65)
18:00:47.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
18:00:47.952 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:237)
18:00:47.952 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:308)
18:00:47.953 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:114)
18:00:47.953 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheFactory.java:179)
18:00:47.954 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:56)
18:00:47.954 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:63)
18:00:47.955 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:284)
18:00:47.956 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:38)
18:00:47.956 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:70)
18:00:47.957 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:70)
18:00:47.957 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:62)
18:00:47.958 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:114)
18:00:47.958 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:97)
18:00:47.959 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:70)
18:00:47.959 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 70 more
18:00:47.960 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
18:00:47.960 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
18:00:47.961 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
18:00:47.962 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
18:00:47.962 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 2.372 secs
```

Comment: Can you post your entire build.gradle file please?

Comment: As you can see from the full build.gradle, I was forced to download the jar for joda time and compile it from the libs folder. But I'd much rather be able to use gradle to download dependencies from jcenter, otherwise I'm missing out on one of the biggest benefits of gradle.

Comment: Have you tried running gradle from the command line in debug mode?  It might reveal where Gradle is trying to find the artifacts.

Comment: I didn't try that, but I just went into the root directory and ran ```./gradlew --stacktrace --debug```. I'll append the results to the questions

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a corrupted Gradle image. Try deleting the .gradle directories in both your home directory and the project and rebuild.

Comment: @ScottBarta: I deleted the .gradle directory from the home directory, but there doesn't appear to be one in the project root.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and was caused by the gradle [proxy settings](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)

If you are using proxy settings, make sure that you have the **HTTPS** proxy set.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using the Dependency with Classifier in your dependencies as described in section [51.4.1.3. Classifiers](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html).

Specifically

```
compile files('libs/joda-time-2.4.jar')
```

for joda time.

Also gradle please is a nice place to find the latest version and format for most gradle dependencies, such as jodatime http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#jodatime.